# jQuery - on dropdown select change my confirm box doesnt work

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".test123").live("change", function () {
        var ddlBrand = "";
        ddlBrand = $('#<%= ddlBrand.ClientID %>').val();

        if (ddlBrand > 0) {
            return confirm('The values entered for this brand will reset. Are you sure you want to change the Brand.');
        });
    }
});
return false;
});
```

The problem that i have with the above code is that on Cancel of confirm box i am not able to retain the page state.
Also for the first dropdown selection i do not want the confirm box.
Please help.

Comment: What do you mean "retain the page state"?

Comment: Also, after formatting your snippet, it's clear that the code is messed up. If it was simply an error when posting this question, please correct.

Comment: Remove that return false. There is no need.

Comment: Please put an alert box after `ddlBrand = $('#<%= ddlBrand.ClientID %>').val();` and check the value of ddlBrand like `alert(ddlBrand);`

Comment: Is it a text or integer?? Let us know...

Comment: You use "return" inside an event handler callback. You cannot return anything from asynchronous callbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, You dont want confirm if ddlBrand change first time, and if confirm calls, Cancel confirmation revert your ddlBrand value with previous selected value. You can try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".test123").on("change", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ddlBrand = $('#<%= ddlBrand.ClientID %>');
        var value = ddlBrand.val();
        var prevValue = ddlBrand.data('prev');

        if ( value > 0 && prevValue && prevValue  != 0) {
            if(confirm('The values entered for this brand will reset. Are you sure you want to change the Brand.')){
                ddlBrand.data('prev', value)
            }else{
                ddlBrand.val(prevValue )
            }
        }else{
            ddlBrand.data('prev', value)
        }
    });
});
```

And Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V6qyQ/)**

Comment: Hi Yograj, this is exactly what i need. But its not working on my page. Not getting any error either.

Comment: Seems like it wouldnt work for DropDownList with Autopostback set to true.

Comment: @PraveenNambiar it will work, just add `e.preventDefault();` and `e` as argument in function(e) like check updated answer.